# Include "abbr" tag within TinyMCE for Episerver CMS 11

Tags: episerver

I'm using Episerver version 11.15.1.0 and EPiServer.UI version 11.25.0.0.

I have a requirement to include  tag within TinyMCE, as shown in below example
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_abbr_test

Please suggest if this is supported in EPiServer CMS.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://tedgustaf.com/blog/2022/adding-custom-tinymce-plugin-to-the-html-editor-in-optimizely-cms/

Comment: Hi @TedNyberg: Thanks for link. I followed same and I'm able to implement in my solution as abbr tag. Only I also need "title" from user input:
<abbr title="userInput">dummyText</abbr>

if you could share any reference that i could use to take input from user and inject as Title as shown above,  i could extend this further.

Comment: If you want to keep it TinyMCE-specific (not involving Optimizely/Dojo), you can use dialogs etc in your plugin: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/dialog/

Comment: Hi @TedNyberg: Thanks for link.. it is useful.  only in e.g.  tinymce.activeEditor.formatter.toggle('mark') is used to toggle but i also need to append "tittle". can you please advise how to add/remove title also to tag "abbr" and under whcih event ?

Answer (score 0):

You could install the TinyMCE plugin, [xhtmlxtras](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-3x/reference/TinyMCE3x@Plugins/Plugin3x@xhtmlxtras/). Then register it as an [external plugin](https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/content-cloud/v11.0.0-content-cloud/docs/plug-ins).

Then you should be able to add "abbr" (and some other buttons) to the toolbar.

Comment: Thanks for information. Can you please advise how to install xhtmlxtras in episerver cms 11 ?

Comment: As I recall, you can put it anywhere you want in your solution. But I like to put in in the modules/_protected folder.

Comment: Basically you can store it in your regular frontend distribution folder. Then use something like this in your TinyMCE configuration (see the link in my original post):
`.AddExternalPlugin("custom-plugin", "UI/dist/editor/plugins/some-name.js");`

Comment: Thanks. I mean from where I can get JS that you referring for xhtmlxtras ?

Comment: `xhtmlxtras` should already be included with TinyMCE, but you have to explicitly add the plugin to your TinyMCE configuration.

Comment: Hi @TedNyberg: Thanks for reply. I have tinyMCE working in my solution but when i did 
.AddPlugin("xhtmlxtras")[in c# code]
, i get error Failed to load plugin: xhtmlxtras from url http://demosite.com/EPiServer/EPiServer.Cms.TinyMce/2.10.1/ClientResources/tinymce/plugins/xhtmlxtras/plugin.min.js  in TinyMCE editor. Does that mean, i need to do any additional settings ?

Comment: I'm not sure it's included in the older TinyMCE versions, you may need to upgrade to V3 of the TinyMCE NuGet package: https://nuget.optimizely.com/package/?id=EPiServer.CMS.TinyMce

Comment: Hi @TedNyberg:  thanks for info, I found that If we are using Episerver.CMS.TinyMCE > 2.0 then the implemented TinyMCE version is over than 4 and it does not have xhtmlxtras plugin. So, i will have to go through custom plugin like https://tedgustaf.com/blog/2022/adding-custom-tinymce-plugin-to-the-html-editor-in-optimizely-cms/

Comment: Aha, didn't realize that plugin was v4 only. :/